# How center 3 boxes in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three boxes, and i need centralized them, but i just don't know what to do.

PHOTO -> -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Of3i.png

HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 box">OPEN BAR + DRINKING GAMES</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 box">CONHECER VÁRIOS BARES E BALADAS EM UMA DAS MAIORES CIDADES DO MUNDO</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 box">CONHECER PESSOAS</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #about .box {
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid white;
      width: 250px;
      height: 350px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      margin-right: 140px;
 }
```

I already try setup margin: 0 auto; to the row class, but its not working at all..

Comment: You mean "center" instead of "centralize"?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them within a div with `.container` class.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 box">OPEN BAR + DRINKING GAMES</div>
       <div class="col-md-4 box">CONHECER VÁRIOS BARES E BALADAS EM UMA DAS MAIORES CIDADES DO MUNDO</div>
       <div class="col-md-4 box">CONHECER PESSOAS</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work. Bootstrap is a fluid grid system so you can't have the width: 250px on your .box.col-X-X and you can't have the margin-right on it either. Pixels are not used if at all possible, especially on column classes. Make a custom row of different elements to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a text-center class which you could apply to your divs.